# C# MVC project shows black page on IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have 2 of the same projects, 1 projects is intranet mvc and the other one is internet mvc.

On Visual Studio 2013 they load and work perfectly fine, but when i publish them to IIS 7 the internet mvc shows a black page and the intranet mvc shows just the same as on Visual Studio 2013, so thats good.

The internet MVC is not showing any error, it's just a blank page and if i view the page source it had an empty head and an empty body.

I have the IIS features turned on:

(language is dutch, sorry)
[image]

Comment: As you can see, ASP.NET is not installed at all. Check all boxes under "Toepassingsontwikkelingsfuncties" (Application Development Features). Or search the web for "iis install asp.net" and follow the steps mentioned, like at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831475.aspx.

Comment: It works when I follow thos steps, but than i don't have a deployed package. And how come that my other application is deployed and is working fine?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @CodeCaster You can deploy a website in visual studio, so the files are dll's, why doesnt it work with the dll files?

Comment: Because you haven't installed ASP.NET. I don't know what your "other application" is or why that one does work.